# bootstrap selectpicker flicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Rearrange the jQuery and also use popper.js with bootstrap 4

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="selectpicker" name = "usertype"   title="User Type"  required="true" data-size="7">
            <option value="0"> test1 </option>
            <option value="2"> test2 </option>
            <option value="4"> test3 r</option>
            <option value="6"> test4 </option>
</select>
 <input name = "first_name"  type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"  required="true" value = "">

 <input name = "last_name"  type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"  required="true" value = "">
```

Comment: provide a demo so we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the jQuery and also use popper.js with bootstrap 4

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="selectpicker" name = "usertype"   title="User Type"  required="true" data-size="7">
            <option value="0"> test1 </option>
            <option value="2"> test2 </option>
            <option value="4"> test3 r</option>
            <option value="6"> test4 </option>
</select>
```